# MySQL Workbench - where is the duplicate table command in the menu?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I try use mysql workbench for windows and can not find command in context menu `duplicate table`.

Anyone can say where this command?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such command to duplicate a table in the SQL IDE. You can manually run [**create table like**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html) and then copy the content over. In modeling you can instead copy a table figure to clipboard and paste it back into the diagram. MySQL Workbench will then ask you if you want to duplicate the object (as it exists already there).

Comment: In the second part of this answer, you refer to "modeling". Does "modeling" here mean ER diagrams? So, there is no table data being copied, right?

Comment: Yes, in the modeling section you only deal with structure, hence: metadata (not table content). ER diagrams are part of the modeling section, indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the Modeling tip!  For others: what he means by the Modeling instructions is simply to right-click the Table name/icon in the "Physical Schemas" Accordion tab, "Tables" panel, and pick "Copy".  Then just right-click on open space in the Tables panel, and you can Paste the copy in.  Then just change the table name.

Comment: The secret is to paste the table back onto the same page of the model as the original. If you don't you end up with the same table diagram on a different page. In that case edits to either table diagram effect the other.

Pasting on the same page allows you to duplicate, then you can move the table to another page with a Cut and Paste. Which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using below first you will be able to Duplicate Table Schema including index and than secondly you will populate data from old table.

```
create table bkpname like tblname;
INSERT bkpname SELECT * FROM tblname;
```